# How do I dual boot linux from a thumb drive on mac?

Tags: linux, mac, dualboot

I am currently using a MacBook Air (Early 2015, i5, 8GB model). I am trying to dual boot Linux in order to familiarise myself with those commands and the OS itself.

I had followed tutorials on downloading the Linux disk image and also tries to enable external boot in the Startup Utilities. However, when I boot into recovery mode and access the startup utility, it doesn't show the enable/disable external boot options. Furthermore, I have also attempted to use Cmd-R upon startup to check whether the computer detects the drive (with Linux disk image on it) but it wasn't able to.

Can anyone help me with this problem? or is there an alternate solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't show as bootable when you hold Opt at boot [none of the others you tried will do it] then the Mac can't see it & you'll need to investigate `rEFInd`

Comment: Any reason not to use a VM rather than dual booting? Something link VirtualBox is free and you can easily install lots of different Linux distro's to try out.

Answer (score 0):

I can give 3 ways to run Linux from a USB.

1. Use a live distribution. In this case, you won't be able to save files on disk. When you reboot, they will be gone.
2. Use a Linux distribution purposed to be run from a USB. Just search for "portable Linux distributions". These distributions provide a way to easily install the distribution on the USB by almost as easily as copying files. Although you will have a lighter OS compared to full distributions like Ubuntu.
3. The regular installation method: Create a bootable installation USB of your preferred Linux distribution and boot it (on Mac you just press and hold "alt" during startup and chose the usb drive from the menu you get). Follow the regular installation process and select the USB drive rather than your internal disk (of course, the USB you want to install Linux must be attached to the computer as well. So 2 USBs: one to perform installation, other to install to). After installation, remove the installation media and keep the USB you installed Linux to. Boot from it buy pressing "alt" on startup.

As far as I know you don't need a third party boot loader like rEFInd. You don't actually dual-booting, in the sense you don't have 2 OSs on same disk. You just need to boot from a USB.